# i created a method in another class but i can't use it in my onClick method from the main class

Tags: sql, android, class, onclick

i created a method called insertTable in a class called Table but i can't use it in my onClick method in the main class :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Table expense = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_1);
    Table income = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_2);
    Button add_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    EditText add = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add);
    add_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

i want to do a income.insertTable in the onClick method but eclipse say that i need to create a local variable.
Can someone help me plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make "income" an instance variable, like this:

```
public class Main {
    private Table income;

    //...
}
```

and change this line:

```
Table income = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_2);
```

to this:

```
income = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_2);
```

You should check out this resource for info about variable scopes:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

The variable `income` doesn't exist in the `onClick()` method because you declared it as local to `onCreate()`. `onClick()` is outside of the [variable's scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm). The easiest solution would be to make `income` "global" to the overall Activity's class:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    private Table income;
    //Some other stuff here

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Table expense = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_1);

        // Notice how this next line has changed; you don't
        // need to specify the type of income since it's
        // already been declared
        income = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_2);
        Button add_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        EditText add = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add);
        add_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        income.insertTable(someTable);
    }
}
```

You could do this with the rest of the objects you've created in `onCreate()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct. I would just like to add in the Android paradigm your going to use Field variables quite a bit. The best way I've found to refactor local variables into fields effectively in ecilpse is:

**Keyboard Shortcut**
Select the local variable
Shift+Alt+t,v

Menu
Select the local variable
Refactor => Convert local variable to field... => OK